# How do I turn off my iPod Touch?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch

I have been having trouble with the use of my iPod Touch.

When I go to turn it off, the voice command screen comes up.

Comment: Please separate these into two questions, as there will be two different answers. This makes it much easier for us to find and answer question,

Comment: Which model is you iPod Touch?  Which version of iOS?

Comment: @bjbk a 64gb iPod Touch and I got the latest update which I think is 6.0 or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, to shut down an iPod touch:

- Hold down the **Sleep/Wake** button on **top** of the device. *(NOT the Home button on the front.)* *Use the [manuals](https://support.apple.com/en_US/manuals/ipodtouch) link below to find the manual for your device.*
- Then "slide to power off" when prompted.

I suspect you may be holding down the **Home** button, which invokes the Voice Command.

From [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201559):

> #### How to restart
>
> - Press and hold the Sleep/Wake button until the red slider appears.
> - Drag the slider to turn your device completely off.
> - After the device turns off, press and hold the Sleep/Wake button again until you see the Apple logo.

You can [download manuals](https://support.apple.com/en_US/manuals/ipodtouch) for iPod touch.

Comment: Okay then where is the power button? My ipod was gift,bought used. so no instructions.

Comment: @Trismegistus at the top

Comment: @Trismegistus You can [download manual for iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en_US/manuals/ipodtouch).

Comment: Thank you @BasilBourque for the link.  The OP may have an older device based on the latest update comment.

Answer (score 2):

To turn the device off hold to "Power" button (Top of the device) until a slide to power off screen appears - Press it and slide your finger across the screen.

If this fails, try holding down the 'Home' button with the 'Power' button for 10 seconds, the device should be off now.

If not; Try this:
Go to the Settings app, General, Tap Accessibility Then click AssistiveTouch (Near the bottom) 
Now there should be a small black square that you can drag around your screen, Tap it, Tap Device then hold the Lock icon until prompted "Slide to power off"